# Kafka Topic has Replication Factor of 3, but Offsets returned are zero for all but 1 Partition

Tags: apache-kafka

[This code example (Github)](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/metadata.rs) demonstrates how to obtain the Metadata for a Kafka Topic, which includes information about current Offsets.

This is an example written in Rust rdkafka, which uses the C++ implementation RDKafka under the hood.

I have experimented with this program on a system I am working on.

Here is some information about the Metadata which I have access to.

```
Topics:
  Topic: [HIDDEN]  Err: None
     Partition: 0  Leader: 123806  Replicas: [123806, 115260, 7075]  ISR: [123806, 115260, 7075]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 1  Leader: 7075  Replicas: [7075, 123806, 123244]  ISR: [7075, 123806, 123244]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 2  Leader: 123244  Replicas: [123244, 7075, 115250]  ISR: [123244, 7075, 115250]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 3  Leader: 115250  Replicas: [115250, 123244, 123790]  ISR: [115250, 123244, 123790]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 4  Leader: 123790  Replicas: [123790, 115250, 115260]  ISR: [123790, 115250, 115260]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 5  Leader: 115260  Replicas: [115260, 123790, 123806]  ISR: [115260, 123790, 123806]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 6  Leader: 123806  Replicas: [123806, 7075, 123244]  ISR: [123806, 7075, 123244]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 7  Leader: 7075  Replicas: [7075, 123244, 115250]  ISR: [7075, 123244, 115250]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 8  Leader: 123244  Replicas: [123244, 115250, 123790]  ISR: [123244, 115250, 123790]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 9  Leader: 115250  Replicas: [115250, 123790, 115260]  ISR: [115250, 123790, 115260]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 7 (difference: 7)
     Partition: 10  Leader: 123790  Replicas: [123790, 115260, 123806]  ISR: [123790, 115260, 123806]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 11  Leader: 115260  Replicas: [115260, 123806, 7075]  ISR: [115260, 123806, 7075]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 12  Leader: 123806  Replicas: [123806, 115250, 123790]  ISR: [123806, 115250, 123790]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Partition: 13  Leader: 7075  Replicas: [7075, 123790, 115260]  ISR: [7075, 123790, 115260]  Err: None
       Low watermark: 0  High watermark: 0 (difference: 0)
     Total message count: 7
```

This particular topic is configured to have a Replication Factor of 3.

However, all of the High Watermark values are zero in the above table, except for 1, which has the value 7.

Why is this? With a replication factor of 3, and with a total of 14 partitions, as shown here, I would expect to see that either all the partitions are synchronized, such that they **all** have a High Watermark value of 7, **or** that 3 of the partitions are in sync (the number of replications) such that 3 of the partitions have a High Watermark of 7.

Answer (score 1):

While asking this question I figured out the answer, which leads me to a slightly different question than the one above.

This might be useful reference information for someone in future.

To answer the above question, one must realize what these numbers mean. To understand that, some terminology:

- Number of "Partitions" for a Topic: As shown above the number of Partitions is 14. The number of partitions is related to how keyed messages are distributed. Messages are distributed to partitions depending on their **Key** values. In this case, I published a total of 7 messages all with the same key, hence these messages all were distributed (partitioned) to the same Partition. That is why all partitions have zero events (messages) except for one which has 7. Messages are distributed by default using a round-robin algorithm based on the hash of the key.
- Number of "Replications" for a Topic: The above data table does **not** show anything **directly** about the number of Replications, but the number can be inferred by the data in the **Replicas** array and **ISR** array. Since the **Replicas** array has length 3, this indicates that the Replication Factor = 3. Since the **ISR** (In Sync Replicas) array contains the same values, this indicates that all of the Replicas are "in-sync". (Meaning they contain all of the events/messages.)

So, the above table of data makes sense. There is only 1 key in use, hence there is only 1 Partition which contains all the messages, all of which have the same key.